# Cartthrob forms not working

Tags: ee2, cartthrob

Www.batterywarehouse.co.uk

All forms except the simple
Front page add to basket forms are failing.

The checkout form redirects to the same page and fails to direct to the external payment provider.

Please help.

Thanks,
Ian

Comment: Have you any examples of your code that's failing? You need to help us if you're going to get some help in return.

Comment: Hi Andrew, probably best if i gave you access to the site. Everything worked, and then all of a sudden the basket, checkout forms all started to fail. I've run through all the suggestions on the docs. I'm pulling my hair out, and so is the client. Any help much appreciated....

Comment: Ok - but there's quite a difference between a code snippet and asking me to look at the site. I'm happy to do that but in the nicest possible way, there would need to be something in it for us. Email me direct if you want to chat further on this.

Comment: Hi Andy, I'm sorry I assumed you were CartThrob support. I have a guy looking at it now, but if all else fails I will come back to you. Thanks again for you input.

Comment: No worries. The Stack Exchange site is largely community support, so people giving up their own time to help others. Hope you manage to get sorted.